# Write $f(t)$ in terms of its complex form

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

The questions states:

given $f(t)=1+\sqrt{3}\sin{2t}+\dfrac{1}{2}\cos{5t}$, what is the complex fourier series of $f(t)$?

My formula sheet tells me that in complex form, it should be written as:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=- \infty} c_ne^{jw_0nt}$
Where according to wikipedia, $c_n=\dfrac{1}{2} (a_k-ib_k)$

Following the formulas, I get that in complex form $f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)e^{ikn}$ where $w_0$ is 1.

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you know the complex Fourier series of $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$?

Comment: You just have to apply the complex definition of $sin(2t)$ and $cos(5t)$

Comment: So I should have written it as $f(t)=1+ \sqrt{3} \dfrac{e^{i2t}+e^{-i2t}}{2i}...$ and so on?

Comment: @Randy Yup. And that's it. That's the final answer. Except $\sin(2t) = \dfrac{e^{i2t} - e^{-i2t}}{2i}$, with a minus in the numerator. Put on the corresponding cosine term, and you're done. Maybe they want it written as $1 - \frac{\sqrt3i}{2}e^{i2t} + \frac{\sqrt3i}{2}e^{-i2t} + \cdots$ instead, but that's merely a matter of aesthetics.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of complex sine and cosine $f(t)=1+\sqrt{3}\frac{e^{i2t}-e^{-i2t}}{2i}+\frac{e^{i5t}+e^{-i5t}}{4}$.

Notice that this is already an equation of the form $\sum^{\infty}_{n=- \infty} c_ne^{iw_0nt}$ where $w_0=0, c_0=1,c_2=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2i}, c_{-2}=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2i},c_5=c_{-5}=\frac{1}{4}$ and $c_n=0$ for all other values.

In fact, some books will define the fourier series as  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=- \infty} c_ne^{iw_0nt}$ and some will define it as $a_0+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n cos(nt)+b_nsin(nt)$, but it is easy to go from one to another using the fact that $sin(nt)=\frac{e^{int}-e^{-int}}{2i}$ and $cos(nt)=\frac{e^{int}+e^{-int}}{2}$.

To check that you have understood this, a nice exercise you can try is to find the relation between $a_n,b_n$ and $c_n$. It shoudn't be too hard.